# Symfony2 controller post initialization callback?

Tags: php, symfony, callback, controller, lifecycle

I have a controller which is calling a service with `$this->get('app.service.myservice')` in many functions handling routes.

Instead of fetching that service systematically, I was wondering whether there is a way of being notified that the controller and the services have been created. I am looking some kind of callback in the controller's life's cycle.

I would then fetch the service once and store it in a variable with the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route dispatcher emits a series of events at each stage in the processing.  Events are not overly documented but you can check the dispatch code as well as:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html

You want to listen for the kernel.controller event:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-controller

Listeners are discussed here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html

Having said that, if all you want to do is to inject a particular service in certain controllers then consider defining your controller as a service as discussed here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Your service definition might look like:

```
cerad_project_tournament_import_controller:
  class: Cerad\ProjectTournament\Import\ImportController
  calls: [[setContainer, ['@service_container']]]
  arguments:
    - '@cerad_project_tournament_importer_excel'
```

With a route of:

```
project_tournament_import:
  path:     /import
  methods:  [GET,POST]
  defaults:
    _controller: cerad_project_tournament_import_controller:importAction
```

And a controller class of:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

final class ImportController extends Controller
{
  private $importer;

  public function __construct(ImporterExcel $importer)
  {
    $this->importer = $importer;
  }
```

Using services will avoid the listener stuff and gives you a cleaner approach.